# Registering Push Notification outside App delegate

Tags: swift, push-notification, ios10

I need to register and unregister push notifications outside the app delegate. I am able to unregister but I am not able to re-register for push notifications.

Comment: what does it mean that you cannot re-register? your phone sets on fire?

Comment: I need to enable and disable push notification within my app. So that i need to register and unregister for push notification. when i try to register outside app delegate the remote notification delegates are not called.

Comment: if you want to do that only on phone side, send user to settings and turn off notifications for app, didReceiveRemoteNotification is not called?

Comment: Thanks @Lu. That solved my problem. I have navigated the user to settings page.